# Can the help section link be added to iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

It's basically in the title.

When viewing SE sites through a browser, there's always a link to the help section easily accessible.

Could such a link be added to the iOS app? I would suggest above "About" on the main menu.

Comment: For a quick tip, you can use the automagical comment shortcuts to get to help quickly, by writing `[help]` (and subpages like `[help/on-topic]`) and clicking the resultant link, and then deleting the comment if required. Or you can hit the "Safari" button on any post (or, of course, bookmark the help sites for the stacks you use most). But I agree that's all cumbersome if you need to access help a lot. For the most part, I don't, except to point newbs at particular language, which makes the `[help]` approach most useful, because I want to offer OP a direct link anyway.

Comment: I appreciate its a duplicate (didn't see it before posting) but the old one is 2 years old and there's no answer to it. What are the chances of this being implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably ask for help to be implemented on a per-site basis.

The about screen can contain many sites, each of which has different help (well the same general framework, but customized close reasons and customized landing pages and tours).

Maybe called out in More Options under Favorite Questions or above the "switch to parent site / switch to meta" toggle in the action section.

Either way - probably a good idea to implement.